# How can I suppress private method invocation in constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I have a very very simple class which has a private method. The question is how to suppress this method invocation?

Here is my code:

```
public class Example { 
    private int value;

    public Example(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        method();
    }

    private void method() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And code of test (attempt at least):

```
public void test() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Example.class, "method");
    final int EXPECTED_VALUE = 1;
    Example example = new Example(EXPECTED_VALUE);
    int RETRIEVED_VALUE = example.getValue();

    assertEquals(RETRIEVED_VALUE, EXPECTED_VALUE);
    verifyPrivate(Example.class, times(1)).invoke("method");
}
```

*UPD*

For me is important to comply with these two terms:

1. `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Example.class, "method");`
2. `PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(Example.class, times(1)).invoke("method");`

Comment: Why on earth would you just throw a new exception? I don't understand.

Comment: `//method();` should do the trick

Comment: It's only an example of real class.

Comment: @Aaron What are you allowed and not allowed to do?

Comment: OK I think he is asking how to mock `method` so that its actual implementation is not called.  It's a "how do I write this unit test?" question.

Comment: I need only to check if `method` was fired but I can't fire it.

Comment: I want to create an Example object without `method` invocation.

Comment: @Aaron The way you've specified the question, it looks like you don't care if exception is thrown or not. Since `value` is set, you could just catch the Exception and continue on.

Comment: would mocking the constructor (and whatever else calls the private method) work?

Comment: Frankly I don't know.

Comment: what I meant was, are you open to that approach?

Comment: No, because I'm testing the constructor. I can't just mock it.

Comment: You stub the dependency after extracting it out to an interface with implementation.

Comment: Could you modify the class Example ?

Comment: I think it is not possible with powermock. If you can't stub the private method may be you can stub what this method does.

Comment: Yes. But in this case I'll test not my constructor, but private method by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't modify the code under test. I think there isn't a perfect solution. You need  to *partially mock* the `Example` instance.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

but you can't do this since you have to instantiate your object at first.

---

So i propose the following workaround composed of two tests. The first test remove the private `method` from the class, instantiate the `Example` and verify that the `Example` is correctly initialized.
The second test instantiate the `Example` and verify that a `RuntimeException` (the private `method` side effect).

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Example.class)
public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void constructor_should_initialize_the_v2alue() throws Exception {
        suppress(method(Example.class, "method"));

        final int EXPECTED_VALUE = 1;
        Example example = PowerMockito.spy(new Example(EXPECTED_VALUE));
        int RETRIEVED_VALUE = example.getValue();

        assertEquals(RETRIEVED_VALUE, EXPECTED_VALUE);
    }

    @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
    public void constructor_should_invoke_the_private_method() throws Exception {
        new Example(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to verify that method was invoked as well (without invocation).

Comment: IMHO, it is not possible with powermock/mockito. May be you can look at runtime weaving/aop with [aspectj](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/)